# Linq to entities ignore casing, NotSupportedException

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I need to look up items from DB context with ignoring case, but can't get it to work, what I've tried so far is:

```
var interestingItem = ctx.MyItems.FirstOrDefault(x => 
      x.Name.IndexOf(item.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0);
```

Also:

```
var interestingItem = ctx.MyItems.FirstOrDefault(x => 
      string.Equals(x.Name, item.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

I've also tried to apply `ToLowerInvariant()`, but always get:

> An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
>   'Int32 IndexOf(System.String, System.StringComparison)' method, and
>   this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither of the methods you are using can be translated to SQL. You'll need to use the `string.Compare` method that takes a boolean `IngoreCase` variable:

```
var interestingItem = ctx.MyItems.FirstOrDefault(x => 
  string.Compare(x.Name, item.Name, true) == 0));
```

Alternatively you could convert both strings to lower case before comparing.

Comment: Good. Works. Also discovered that `Contains`, which is translated to `SQL LIKE` is case insensitive in `SQL Server`, which would work in my case, where names are unique.

Comment: @ErkiM. - `Contains` (and hence `LIKE`) will be slower than the equals comparison, but whether that affects your application would only be evident with testing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .ToLower() which should be supported.

```
  var interestingItem = ctx.MyItems.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.ToLower() == item.Name.ToLower());
```